# Creating per-user php5-fpm pools the secure way

Tags: apache, fastcgi, php, mod-fastcgi

When creating per-user php5-fpm pools on an Apache mod_fastcgi setup which of the following is the most secure way and efficient way of granting webserver permissions to the PHP pool?

## Option 1:

Set the group to `www-data`:

```
listen.owner = username
listen.group = www-data
listen.mode = 0660

user = username
group = www-data
```

While this works files created by PHP would have the ownership set to **username:www-data** while files uploaded via SCP will have **username:username**.

---

## Option 2:

Add `www-data` to the supplementary group `username`:

```
listen.owner = username
listen.group = username
listen.mode = 0660

user = username
group = username
```

-

```
usermod -aG username www-data
```

---

Which of these options are secure? You may also share a better method.

I checked the following guides:

- http://www.howtoforge.com/php-fpm-nginx-security-in-shared-hosting-environments-debian-ubuntu
- http://www.binarytides.com/php-fpm-separate-user-uid-linux/

But they were all written before bug [#67060](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67060) was discovered and fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I am using following setup on my LEMP (Nginx + PHP-FPM). For Apache this should also be applicable.

PHP-FPM runs several pools as `nobody:user1`, `nobody:user2` ...

Nginx runs as `nginx:nginx`

User `nginx` is a member of each `user1`, `user2`.. groups:

```
# usermod -a -G user5 nginx
```

File permissions:

```
root:root    drwx--x--x   /home
user1:user1  drwx--x---   /home/user1                       (1)
user1:user1   rwxr-x---   /home/user1/site.com/config.php   (2)
user1:user1  drwxrwx---   /home/user1/site.com/uploads      (3)
nobody:user1  rw-rw----   /home/user1/site.com/uploads/avatar.gif   (4)
```

(1) User's home dir has no `x` permission for `other`, so php-fpm pool running as `nobody:user2` will not have access to `/home/user1` and vice versa.

(2) php script doesn't have `w` for `group`, so it cannot create files in htdocs.

(3) On `uploads` dir we should manually enable write access for group `user1`, to enable php script to put files there. Don't forget to disable php handler for `uploads`, in nginx this is made by

```
server {
    ....
    location ^~ /uploads/ { }
```

but for Apache you should check.

(4) uploaded files should also have `w` for `group` if we want `user1` to be able to edit these files later via ftp or ssh (logging in as `user1:user1`). Php code is also editable via ftp since `user1` is its `owner`.

Nginx will have `read` access to all users and `write` access to all user's uploads since user `nginx` is a member of each `user1`, `user2`, ... groups. 
You should not forget to add it to all later groups. You can also modify `useradd` script to do it automatically.